# DOM Property values in Selenium

Tags: selenium, dom, automation, attributes

Can anyone help me to know how we can get property values which are present in `DOM` but not as attributes in `HTML`

For example-

For below HTML - it doesn't list the property like `scrollTopmax`,`cols` and these property can I find in `DOM`. How to get such property value from `DOM`

```
<textarea class="siebui-ctrl-textarea siebui-align-left siebui-input-align-left s_3_1_0_0" name="s_3_1_0_0" aria-labelledby="Text_Label" aria-label="Benefits" style="height: 64px; width: 824px;" maxlength="2000" tabindex="0" data-seq="0" readonly="readonly" aria-readonly="true"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are we suppose to guess how the html looks like? add it to your question.

Comment: Which _property values_ are you looking from the DOM?

Comment: can u show in screen shot?

Comment: I still don't see the property like `scrollTopmax`, `cols` in the HTML you have provided. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you don't say what your programming language, but we can tell selenium to execute Javascript to the browser by using function `execute_script` or `executeScript`.

Python example

```
cols = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('textarea').cols")
print(cols)
# 20
```

C# example

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string cols= (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('textarea').cols");
```

note: `scrollTopMax` is non-standard attribute and available only in Firefox